# Updating software from a downloaded file

Tags: updates

I have a programme installed and now I need to update to the most recent version which I have downloaded from their website as zip file. How can I update it?

Thank you.

Comment: Usually, you just install the updated version and it overwrites the existing version with the new version. Do you expect this to be any different?

Comment: no, but wanted to confirm because I'm a dummie :-) thank you.

Comment: It should just write over the old version. If the program is running, be sure to restart it.